# Colorbar limits are not respecting set vmin/vmax in plt.contourf. How can I more explicitly set the colorbar limits?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Getting a strange result when trying to adjust the data range when plotting using contourf

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, vmin = 0, vmax = 3)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Results in this for me:
[image]

It's like the colors match the vmin/vmax I set, but the number range displayed on the colorbar remains what it would be without setting vmin/vmax.

In this case, I would like the end result to have a colorbar that ranges from 0 to 3.

Comment: This is the expected result; values below the colornormalization will be colored in the lowest colormap color. Your question lacks a problem description. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: Edited for clarity. In this case, I would like the end result to have a colorbar that ranges from 0 to 3.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, the response, marked as answer, is erroneous (see my comments above), but helped me to come up with two other solutions.

As JulianBauer pointed out in a comment below, the function `mlab.bivariate_normal` used by the OP is not available any more.
To provide functional code that produces output that can be compared with the other answers I am calling the following function, with the definition of `bivariate_normal` copied from the [matplotlib repository](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/81e8154dbba54ac1607b21b22984cabf7a6598fa/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L1866):

```
def myfunction():

    def bivariate_normal(X, Y, sigmax=1.0, sigmay=1.0, mux=0.0, muy=0.0, sigmaxy=0.0):
        """copied from here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/81e8154dbba54ac1607b21b22984cabf7a6598fa/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L1866"""
        Xmu = X-mux
        Ymu = Y-muy
        rho = sigmaxy/(sigmax*sigmay)
        z = Xmu**2/sigmax**2 + Ymu**2/sigmay**2 - 2*rho*Xmu*Ymu/(sigmax*sigmay)
        denom = 2*np.pi*sigmax*sigmay*np.sqrt(1-rho**2)
        return np.exp(-z/(2*(1-rho**2))) / denom

    delta = 0.025
    x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
    y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z1 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    Z2 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
    Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)
    return X,Y,Z
```

**1. A simple and straight forward solution**

Make use of the extend command while providing custom levels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X,Y,Z = myfunction()

plt.figure()
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
levels = np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 7)
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=levels, cmap=cm.coolwarm, extend='min')

colorbar = plt.colorbar(CS)

plt.show()
```

[image: output method 1]

**2. A more complicated solution**

is provided in the answer above, though it needs to be adapted to specific cases and one can easily end up with a colorbar whose levels differs from those in the actual plot. I find this dangerous, so I attempted to wrap it up in a function that can safely be called in any context:

```
def clippedcolorbar(CS, **kwargs):
    from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
    from numpy import arange, floor, ceil
    fig = CS.ax.get_figure()
    vmin = CS.get_clim()[0]
    vmax = CS.get_clim()[1]
    m = ScalarMappable(cmap=CS.get_cmap())
    m.set_array(CS.get_array())
    m.set_clim(CS.get_clim())
    step = CS.levels[1] - CS.levels[0]
    cliplower = CS.zmin<vmin
    clipupper = CS.zmax>vmax
    noextend = 'extend' in kwargs.keys() and kwargs['extend']=='neither'
    # set the colorbar boundaries
    boundaries = arange((floor(vmin/step)-1+1*(cliplower and noextend))*step, (ceil(vmax/step)+1-1*(clipupper and noextend))*step, step)
    kwargs['boundaries'] = boundaries
    # if the z-values are outside the colorbar range, add extend marker(s)
    # This behavior can be disabled by providing extend='neither' to the function call
    if not('extend' in kwargs.keys()) or kwargs['extend'] in ['min','max']:
        extend_min = cliplower or ( 'extend' in kwargs.keys() and kwargs['extend']=='min' )
        extend_max = clipupper or ( 'extend' in kwargs.keys() and kwargs['extend']=='max' )
        if extend_min and extend_max:
            kwargs['extend'] = 'both'
        elif extend_min:
            kwargs['extend'] = 'min'
        elif extend_max:
            kwargs['extend'] = 'max'
    return fig.colorbar(m, **kwargs)
```

The main commands in the function correspond to what kilojoules proposes in his/her answer, but more lines are required to avoid all the explicit and potentially erroneous assignments by extracting all information from the `contourf` object.

Usage:

The OP asks for levels from 0 to 3. The darkest blue represents values below 0, so I find an extend-marker useful.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X,Y,Z = myfunction()

plt.figure()
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=6, vmin=0.0, vmax=3.0, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

colorbar = clippedcolorbar(CS)

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

The extend marker can be disabled by calling `clippedcolorbar(CS, extend='neither')` instead of `clippedcolorbar(CS)`.

[image: output with extend='neither']

Comment: It looks like there are 4 shades of blue (not counting the gray color) in the plot but 3 in the color bar.

Comment: @kilojoules touché, I made an error somewhere. Will have a look at it tomorrow. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yup! Also the color bar values are not evenly spaced, which is something I think the OP wanted.

Comment: the uneven spacing was due to the fact that I had forgotten to update the image.

Comment: I updated the code to also include the lowest and highest color value in the colorbar. This fixes all the issues you pointed out @kilojoules

Comment: @Bastian Your example is not working any more due to the removal of `mlab.bivariate_normal` ( see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/api_changes.html#matplotlib-mlab-removals ). A minimal alternative would be `Z = X-Y`

Comment: Thank you @JulianBauer for pointing that out. I updated the answer to make it functional again.

Answer (score 15):

We can explicitly set the colorbar limits by sending a scalar mappable to `colorbar`.

```
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 5, vmin = 0., vmax = 2., cmap=cm.coolwarm)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.coolwarm)
m.set_array(Z)
m.set_clim(0., 2.)
plt.colorbar(m, boundaries=np.linspace(0, 2, 6))
```

[image]

**Edit**

See Bastian's answer for a complete solution. The problem with my approach is that the segments of the color bar don't correspond to the segments of the contour plot. They use the same coloring scale, but the contour plot and color bar have divided the color scale in different ways. Using the correct lower/upper bounds, this solution gives 6 levels of the contour plot and 6 levels of the colorbar. Since the contour plot and color bar have different bounds, the color segments are different.

Comment: My problem with this is that the colorbar is not segmented into distinct levels.

Comment: @user3826115 I changed my answer. I now send `boundaries=np.arange(0,3.1,.5)` to `colorbar`.

Comment: **I think that this answer is wrong!** The patch corresponding to the highest value contains values ranging from 1.5 to 2.0 according to the color bar. However it has a smaller shape than the corresponding area in the plot above. Plus, then there is a grayish tone of blue in the plot which I don't recognize in the color bar.

Comment: @Bastian Thanks for pointing that out. The underlying data has a maximum less than three but I set the color max to be three. I arbitrarily chose the bins in the color bar. I updated my example so that the colors in the color bar and filled contours match this time.

Comment: @kilojoules your response still contains an error. `Z.max()` evaluates to 1.6996386266249106 so I would expect a corresponding dark red patch which is lacking. Also the colors in the plot and in the colorbar don't match.