# Customizing the limits on the matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset which plots concentration as the z-value.  Note the oddball limits in the colorbar which are mapped to the limits of the z-value.  What I want is to have the colorbar limits go from 0 to some max value (logically the first rounded integer beyond z_max).

[plot of concentrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe1ue.png)

Here is the code snippet:

```
from numpy import *
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
.
.
.

monthly_concentration_array=master_yearly_df.to_numpy()
year_axis_values=master_yearly_df.index.to_numpy()
month_numbers=arange(12)

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,15))

contour_plot=ax.contourf(month_numbers,
    year_axis_values,monthly_concentration_array,levels=40,cmap='rainbow')
colour_bar=fig.colorbar(contour_plot)
```

I naively used

```
colour_bar.set_clim(0,5)
```

But I received a deprecation warning:

MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The set_clim function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use ScalarMappable.set_clim instead.

One other post suggested doing

```
colour_bar.mappable.set_clim(0,5)
```

But that did not work.  I am very confused because the vast majority of posts etc predate matplotlib 3.1 and sadly I don't have enough under-the-hood experience to understand what the reference
"Use ScalarMappable.set_clim instead"  means.

So what is the correct, current way to set colorbar limits so that the scale goes from 0 to 5 when the data only goes from 0.15 to 4.7?

many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the option `vmin=0, vmax=5` in `ax.contourf()`, it will override the default color scaling.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  It turns out that not asking the EXACT question in Google doesn't help.  Changing the wording led me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150687/colorbar-limits-are-not-respecting-set-vmin-vmax-in-plt-contourf-how-can-i-more