# Add legend to a matplotlib scatter plot where colors are dynamic

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I created a Scatter plot using Matplolib and a Pandas dataframe, now i'd like to add a legend to it. Here is my code:

```
colors = ['red' if x >= 150 and x < 200 else 
          'green' if x >= 200 and x < 400 else
          'purple' if x >= 400 and x < 600 else
          'yellow' if x >= 600 else 'teal' for x in myData.R]


ax1.scatter(myData.X, myData.Y, s=20, c=colors, marker='_', label='Test')
ax1.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

What happens here is that, according to the value of `myData.R`, the color of the point in the scatter plot will change. So, since the color is "dynamic", i'm having a lot of troubles creating the legend. The actual code will only create a legend with a single label called 'Test' without any color attached near to it.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
       X  Y    R
0      1  945  1236.334519
0      1  950   212.809352
0      1  950   290.663847
0      1  961   158.156856
```

I tried [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html), but what i didn't understand is:

1. How do i set labels to the legend dynamically? For example, my code says `'red' if x >= 150`, so on the legend there should be a red square with *>150* near to it. But since i'm not adding any label manually, i'm having troubles understanding this.
2. After trying the following, i only got a legend with a single label 'Classes':

`legend1 = ax1.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(),
loc="lower left", title="Classes")

ax1.add_artist(legend1)`

Any kind of advice is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure, but it says in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) that the scatter plot should have a `cmap` and `vmin` and `vmax` parameters. Don't they solve your problem? Instead of a legend, you could have a custom color bar..

Comment: Another idea would be to split up `myData.X` and `myData.Y` beforehand into the specific colored datasets according to `myData.R` and add each subset as extra scatter plot to your figure with a fixed color and label.

Comment: @RolandDeschain So the idea is to make a scatter plot for all the red elements, another one for the green elements and so on? Wouldn't it take more time to generate, though?

Comment: depends on how many datapoints you have. The plotting itself shouldn't be the issue, the separation into the subsets is probably what takes the longest, but could be fast if you can do it in some vectorized fashion with numpy. Is this for some sort of animation?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150687/colorbar-limits-are-not-respecting-set-vmin-vmax-in-plt-contourf-how-can-i-more) is shown what I meant with the color bar (in the answer). You could just create custom ranges and plot the complete dataset, the plot is then in the color according to your settings in the colorbar. Scatter plots support those as well.

Comment: Not for some sort of animation but i'd like the chart to be generated as quickly as possible for my application; i want to check if there are solutions that don't involve splitting the dataset first, if there aren't i will go with your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part of the code that can be sped up is creating a list of strings using a plain Python loop.
Pandas uses numpy's filtering quite efficiently.
Drawing the scatterplot mostly depends on the number of points, which doesn't change when all points are drawn at once or drawn separately in five parts.

Some example code using matplotlib's scatter in a loop:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 500
myData = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.round(np.random.uniform(-1000, 1000, N), -2), 
                       'Y': np.random.uniform(-800, 800, N)})
myData['R'] = np.sqrt(myData.X ** 2 + myData.Y ** 2)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

bounds = [150, 200, 400, 600]
colors = ['teal', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'gold']
for b0, b1, col in zip([None]+bounds, bounds+[None], colors):
    if b0 is None:
        filter = (myData.R < b1)
        label = f'$ R < {b1} $'
    elif b1 is None:
        filter = (myData.R >= b0)
        label = f'${b0} ≤ R $'
    else:
        filter = (myData.R >= b0) & (myData.R < b1)
        label = f'${b0} ≤ R < {b1}$'
    ax1.scatter(myData.X[filter], myData.Y[filter], s=20, c=col, marker='_', label=label)
ax1.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib's scatterplot]

Alternatively, pandas' `cut` can be used to create categories and seaborn's features such as its `hue` parameter can do coloring and automatically create a legend.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

N = 500
myData = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.round( np.random.uniform(-1000, 1000, N),-2), 'Y': np.random.uniform(-800, 800, N)})
myData['R'] = np.sqrt(myData.X ** 2 + myData.Y ** 2)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

bounds = [150, 200, 400, 600]
colors = ['teal', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'gold']

hues = pd.cut(myData.R, [0]+bounds+[2000], right=False)
sns.scatterplot(myData.X, myData.Y, hue=hues, hue_order=hues.cat.categories, palette=colors, s=20, marker='_', ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn scatterplot]

Comment: Nice! Both ways are very efficient, i think i'll go with the first one since i want to stick with MPL, without adding new dependencies such as Seaborn. Thank you a lot !

Comment: I also found another solution, but it's "hacky": https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html, basically it would create the legend independetly from the plot, of course doing like you suggested is way better because the legend is generated directly from the data